# Why does ES6's Map.forEach iterate with 'value, key' instead of 'key, value'?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, foreach, ecmascript-6

As shown on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach), `Map`'s `forEach` callback is called with value first, and then key. E.g.:

`map.forEach(function(value, key, map) { ... })`

Seems like `key, value` is a lot more common than `value, key`. Even the [`Map` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) expects an array of `[key, value]` pairs.

Comment: I usually need the value only, and would end up writing something like `.map(function(_, value) { ... });`

Comment: I don't now if it is more 'common', e.g. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Comment: fyi `Array.prototype.amp` is described in ECMA-262 Edition 5 http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19

Comment: I think the reason is that it better aligns with forEach method of the Array.

Comment: This was probably chosen for consistency with [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), whose callback function takes its parameters in the order `value`, `index`, where map items (obviously) are accessed by key rather than by index.

Comment: What do you mean by "more common"? More common in what context?

Comment: It's worth noting that the MDN documentation for [`Map.prototype.forEach...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Methods) itself states "Calls callbackFn once for each **_key-value_** pair present in the Map object, in insertion order." It links to more complete documentation elsewhere that correctly indicates the value/key order, but in this prime location the only mention is in the incorrect key/value order. Seems a little misleading. Thanks for asking a reasonable and useful question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's probably just for laziness sake.  Most forEach loops will only care about the `value` itself.  By supplying it as the first parameter, you can construct a function that only accepts one parameter:

```
map.forEach(function (value) { /* do something with value */; })
```

Instead of

```
map.forEach(function (unused, value) { /* do something with value */; })
```

Comment: Or even `map.forEach(val => val)` vs `map.forEach((key, val) => val)`

Comment: Hm, yeah, that makes sense. It bit me though when I first used it recently, hence the SO question...

Comment: Yeah, by analogy with `Array.map`, whose callback takes `value, index, array`, it makes a lot of sense.